# Generating sums algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, math, sum

I have to build a code for algorithm. What I have to achieve with my algorithm is the following:

I have three numbers, 4,6,8. I have to generate sums with two of those numbers and then all sums with three of those numbers and then with four and so forth. Ofcourse there can be duplicates like in this example: 4+4+6

I got to idea to use "for" loops, so sums with two of those numbers can be generated with two nested for loops. Three nested "for" loops would give sums of three numbers etc...

I can constrain this solution by using "for" for example up until sums of five numbers, but that is not a general solution.

Is there a way or algoritm or mathematical method to do this?

There is a resemblance with math combinatorics.

Comment: Yes, you can just use recursion. It might also be helpful to include example input with the complete expected output so exactly what you're trying to do is 100% clear.

Comment: If you take into account that x+x+x+...+x (n times) = x*n, you may be able to avoid recursion and get increased performance.

Comment: @n.m. To avoid recursion you need to do much more than that, as it will not solve 5+3=4+4.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment (asking for expected output, which should still please be provided) - do you want to actually generate all the sums, i.e. 4, 6, 8, 4+4, 4+6, 4+8, 6+6, 6+8, 8+8, etc.? And, if so, do you just want the unique sums, all sums or do you want to output the actual numbers that make up the sum? (i.e. 4+8 = 6+6, so do you want to print "4+8" and "6+6", or "12" once, or "12" twice?)

Comment: Well of course there are duplicate sums. I planned to remove duplicate sums and keep only distinct. But that was second pard of the process. I thought, generate all available sums, put them in array and then remove duplicates. Lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two loops for any given number of terms.  Say you want the sum of n values.  For any given sum you have n<sub>8</sub> times the 8, n<sub>6</sub> times the 6 and n<sub>4</sub> times the 4, with n<sub>8</sub>+n<sub>6</sub>+n<sub>4</sub>=n.  To generate all possible combinations you only need to loop over n<sub>8</sub> and n<sub>6</sub>, the value for n<sub>4</sub> can be calculated from that.  In Python:

```
def findsums(n):
    # n8 = [0..n]
    for n8 in range(n+1):
        #n6 = [0..n-n8]
        for n6 in range(n+1-n8):
            n4 = n - n8 - n6 
            # build the string consisting of n terms
            s = "+8" * n8 + "+6" * n6 + "+4" * n4
            # print, and strip the first '+' character
            print( "{0}={1}".format( s[1:], 8*n8+6*n6+4*n4 ) )

findsums(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can derivate your solution from a [Power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

The difference is that in your case, you can have duplicates and it seems that you have a max size for the subsets.

A lot of implementations are available on the internet.

Comment: While correct for the general case - with some limitations on the input (elements are relatively small integers) - this can be done much more efficiently than generating all subsets and summing by exploiting Dynamic Programming and the behavior of sum function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and assuming your elements are all small integers, it is solveable efficiently using dynamic programming in pseudo-polynomial time.

```
f(0,i) = true
f(x,i) = false   if n < 0
f(x,i) = f(x,i-1) OR f(x-arr[i],i-1)
```

Each number `x` such that `f(x,_)=true` is an answer. It can be done by avoiding recursion:

```
table <- int [sum(array)+1][n+1] //2 dimensional table
init table[x][0]=false for each x!=0
init table[0][i]=true for each i
for each x in 1:sum(arr)+1:
    for each i in 1:n+1:
        if x-arr[i] >= 0:
             table[x][i] = table[x][i-1] OR table[x-arr[i]][i-1]
        else:
             table[x][i] = table[x][i-1]
//done generating table, output answers:
for each x in 1:summ(arr)+1:
     if (table[x][n] ==true) print x
```

This answer assumes there is no limit to the size of the subset - if there is, it can be done by adding another dimension to the table.

Run time is `O(sum(arr)*n)`